# appending one div in another div before last div jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have div like

```
<div id='main'>
  <div id='child'>my static content</div>
</div>

$('#main').append("<div class='mycontent'>I'm new box by append</div>");
or
$('#main').appendTo("<div class='mycontent'>I'm new box by append</div>");
```

i know i can use **append() and appendTo** method to insert anything into main div. but i need to know that how can i insert content into main div before child div. content will be pushed into main div before child div. please help me with concept.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/before/

if you want it before the last child div:

```
$("#main > div:last-child").before("<div class='mycontent'>I'm new box by append</div>");
```

or if you want it before a specific div:

```
$("#child").before("<div class='mycontent'>I'm new box by append</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```
$('#main #child').before('<p>Something</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#child').before("<div class='mycontent'>I'm new box by append</div>");
```

also maybe will be useful:

```
$('#child').after("<div class='mycontent'>I'm new box by append</div>");
```

Comment: wrong, because this would add hte new div before main and not before the last div withing main